# jquery submit form to servlet but getParameter() return null

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP that will submit the form to servlet, I want to submit the form using jquery because I want to validate the input field of the form, below is my jquery:

```
function submitForm()
{
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if(name == "")
    {
        alert("Please fill in all fields");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Submit pet form.");
        $('#pet_form').submit();
    }
}
```

below is my form:

```
<form action="Create" method="POST" id="pet_form">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="20" autofocus="true" />
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()" />
</form>
```

after I submit from I get the parameter from servlet:

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
if(name == null)
{
    System.out.println("name == null");
}
```

why I always get null from the code above?

Comment: What do you have in your request ?

Comment: @BobSwager sorry I dont get what you mean

Comment: You're getting parameter from request. What do you have in your request ? 
Does your function pass the parameters to server side ?

Comment: @BobSwager request isn't get the data from submitted form?

Comment: I don't know. I'm asking you :)

Comment: Why don't you use ajax call to submit your form instead: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: @BobSwager normally we uses 'request.getParameter("param")` to get the value from the submitted form isn't it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145317/discussion-between-bob-swager-and-newbie).